# mosquitto_pub do not publish when crontab -e, but do when run the same script in terminal

Tags: python

I ran the below script on terminal and it published all 4 topics; but when running it with crontab -e, every minute, it published only pm25 topics. The aqi values are calculated from the ready-made python module I downloaded from: [python-aqi function](https://pypi.org/project/python-aqi/) What could be the cause of problem?
Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# to get pm2.5 from Home Assistant Rest API xiaomi airpurifier in Mezzanine and Bedroom
# then calculate aqi by using python aqi module obtained from https://pypi.org/project/python-aqi/
# output 4 topics:
#   xiaomi_airpuriier/bedroom/pm25 999
#   xiaomi_airpuriier/bedroom/aqi 999
#   xiaomi_airpuriier/mezzanine/pm25 999
#   xiaomi_airpuriier/mezzanine/aqi 999
# crontab -e every minute

bedroom=$(curl -s GET \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLC.....gEZfY" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    http://localhost:8123/api/states/sensor.xiaomi_airpurifier_air_quality_pm25)
mezzanine=$(curl -s GET \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLC.....gEZfY" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    http://localhost:8123/api/states/sensor.xiaomi_airpurifier_air_quality_pm252)


bedroom_pm25=$(echo "$bedroom" | python3 -c "import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)['state'])")
bedroom_aqi=$(aqi aqi.algos.epa pm25:$bedroom_pm25)
mezzanine_pm25=$(echo "$mezzanine" | python3 -c "import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)['state'])")
mezzanine_aqi=$(aqi aqi.algos.epa pm25:$mezzanine_pm25)


#echo $bedroom_pm25 $bedroom_aqi $mezzanine_pm25 $mezzanine_aqi

# publish to mqtt
mosquitto_pub -h localhost -t xiaomi_airpurifier/bedroom/pm25 -m $bedroom_pm25
mosquitto_pub -h localhost -t xiaomi_airpurifier/bedroom/aqi -m $bedroom_aqi
mosquitto_pub -h localhost -t xiaomi_airpurifier/mezzanine/pm25 -m $mezzanine_pm25
mosquitto_pub -h localhost -t xiaomi_airpurifier/mezzanine/aqi -m $mezzanine_aqi
```

Comment: pls, show the crontab entry here.

Comment: Where does your `aqi` script live?  Is that location on the `$PATH` that is established for crontab jobs?

Comment: The script is in my user login home directory, /home/bthoven. The crontab for this script was creat with crontab -e, without sudo. The script was actually running as I monitor the topic with mqtt explorer, and only the pm25 topics were published every minute. When I run the script manually, at /home/bthoven, all four topics were published without problems. So I suspect the aqi calculator module, written with Python, may be the culprit, but I don’t know how to resolve it.

Comment: the python code is at  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aqi/algos/epa.py

Comment: (solved). I need to explicitly specify the folder location of the aqi command: From aqi aqi.algos.epa...... to: /usr/local/bin/aqi aqi.algos.epa.....

Answer (score 0):

The xiaomi airpurifier bash script in crontab -e

[image]